# update command in database in visual studio c#...but it gives a syntax error

Tags: asp.net

```
SqlCommand query=new SqlCommand("update registration set Name='"+name+
 "',Gender='"+gender+"',Blood_Group='"+blood+"',Date_Of_Birth='" +
 dateTimePicker1+"',City='"+city+"',Phone_Number='" + phone +
 "',Email='"+email+
 "'  where Id='"+id+"','"+username +
 "','"+pass+"','"+utype+"'",conn);
 query.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Have you ever heard about Sql Injection?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.Please take time out for a [tour](http://stackoverflow.com//tour) and visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com//help). You might also want to read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com//questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Also the WHERE clause requires the name of the field for every condition and. if you have many conditions, you need to apply the logical OR or AND operator between the conditions.

Comment: Are you storing passwords as plaintext in your database?

Comment: Hello, cloud you please add to your question what does the syntax error says?thank you

Comment: Please try moving the above update statement to a stored procedure and pass the value as parameters.
I am going to assume the code is for non production, so the statement should be 
SqlCommand query=new SqlCommand("update registration set Name='"+name+ "',Gender='"+gender+"',Blood_Group='"+blood+"',Date_Of_Birth='" +
 dateTimePicker1+"', City='"+city+"',Phone_Number='" + phone + "',Email='"+email+ "' where Id='"+id+"' AND username ='"+username +
 "' AND password ='"+pass+"' AND uType ='"+utype+"'",conn);

Comment: Learn how to use parameterized queried and learn how to do that **now**. Next learn about best practices for password storage and retrieval. Except for trivial learning exercises (and even then it's questionable) passwords should **never** be stored in plain text, they should *always* be one-way hashed.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to StackOverflow,

For a better understanding of how SqlCommand works, try reading [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.8)

I advice you to add more information about your error

I tried to refactor your code a little, to help you with your problem:

1) First we create a string that will store your query and will use "@" character to note variable names

```
            string query =
            $"UPDATE registration " +
            $"SET Name = @name," +
            $"  Gender = @gender," +
            $"  Blood_Group = @blood," +
            $"  Date_Of_Birth = @datedime'," +
            $"  City = @city" +
            $"  Phone_Number = @phone" +
            $"  Email = @email " +
            $"WHERE Id = @id AND " +
            $"  username = @unsername AND" +
            $"  password = @pass AND " +
            $"  utype = @userType";
```

2) Then we open SqlConnection like this:

```
           SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)
```

3) Next, we instantiate the command, and add the parameters

```
           SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);

           command.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar(30));//max length 30 characters
           command.Parameters["@name"].Value = name;// here you assign your variables

           command.Parameters.Add("@gender", SqlDbType.VarChar(1));
           command.Parameters["@gender"].Value = gender;
```

4) Continue by adding with all the other variables you have, in the same way, if you struggle with which SqlDbType to chose, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqldbtype?view=netframework-4.8) you have all types meaning

I hope I could help, don't be afraid to ask, and demand clarifications, good luck!